How to update border style on click of touchable opacity in react native (using expo)
I am bit new to react native, I am fetching parameters from my previous screen and based on that parameters i'm getting data from API.
I'm using flatlist to display those data (in touchableOpacity), now I want that if any item clicked - its border color should get changed from RED to GREEN.
below is my code
import { View, Text,TextInput, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigation, useRouter, useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from '../../../constants/Colors'



export default function index() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { course, div } = useLocalSearchParams()
    console.log({course, div})
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [selectedStuId, setSelectedStuId] = React.useState(1);

    const changeSelectedStudent = function (id) {
        console.log(selectedStuId);
        setSelectedStuId(id);
        console.log(selectedStuId);
      };

    useEffect(()=>{
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown:false
          })
       

      },[])

      useEffect(()=>{

        const getUserAuthentication = async () => {
          try {
            
              if(!course && !div)
              {
                ToastAndroid.show('Something went wrong',ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
                return;
              }
    
            const response = await fetch(
              'https://www.mywebsite.com/fetchStudentListAPI.php',
              {
                method:'POST',
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  firstParam: course,
                  secondParam: div
                }),
              }
            );
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);
           
           
           // return json;
            console.log(json[0].stu_name);
            
    
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        };
        getUserAuthentication();
          
    
    
      },[])

     

  return (
    <View style={{
        padding:25,
        paddingTop:50,
        backgroundColor:Colors.WHITE,
        height:'100%'
      }}>
      <Text style={{
        fontFamily:'Poppins-Bold',
        fontSize:30,
        textAlign:'center'
      }}>Take Attendance</Text>

<Text style={{
        fontFamily:'Poppins-Bold',
        fontSize:18,
        textAlign:'center'
      }}>Course: {course} Div: {div}</Text>

      

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList 
        data={data}
        extraData={setSelectedStuId}
        renderItem={({ item }) => 
            
            <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        changeSelectedStudent(item.stu_id);
                    }}>
            <Text style={item.stu_id === setSelectedStuId // <-- match id property
                          ? styles.item
                          : styles.itemSelected}>{item.stu_roll_no} {item.stu_name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
            
        
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.stu_id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>

    <TouchableOpacity  style={{
        padding:20,
        backgroundColor:Colors.PRIMARY,
        borderRadius:15,
        marginTop:50
      }}>
        <Text style={{
          color:Colors.WHITE,
          textAlign:'center',
          fontFamily:'Poppins'
          }}> Submit </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>


    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      padding: 50,
      flex: 1,
    },
    item: {
      padding: 20,
      fontSize: 15,
      marginTop: 5,
      borderWidth:1,
      borderRadius:15,
      borderColor:Colors.GREEN,
      fontFamily:'Poppins',
    },
    itemSelected: {
        padding: 20,
        fontSize: 15,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:15,
        borderColor:Colors.RED,
        fontFamily:'Poppins',
      },
    
  });


So , you have already changed the border color in click. what is the issue that you are getting?

You can use new Pressable component instead of TouchableOpacity. It takes pressed parameter for style prop and you can use it to change borderColor or any style of your item. You can also use the pressed prop on the child Components of the Pressable. Here is a working example:


<Pressable
  onPress={() => {
    setTimesPressed(current => current + 1);
  }}
  style={({pressed}) => [
    {
      backgroundColor: pressed ? 'green' : 'red',
    },
    styles.wrapperCustom,
  ]}>
  {({pressed}) => <Text style={styles.text}>{pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Press Me'}</Text>}
</Pressable>



Hope this helps.
